# Can we use or transform a strong algorithm for TSP to find value of Hash function?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, np-hard

I know that TSP belongs to NP-hard problems. But if there is a strong algorithm for TSP, can it be used to find a value of hash(inverse hash)and how?

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: Hash inversion isn't necessarily an NP-hard problem (depends on the hash function, most of the time it's not) so there's no reason why a TSP solution would allow you to solve it generally. More reading: https://www.quora.com/Is-cryptographic-hash-inversion-believed-to-be-NP-complete-or-NP-hard-etc

Comment: Just because a problem is NP-complete, it doesn't mean that all other polynomial-time algorithms can be reduced to it in any useful way. The chain of reductions that you would need to follow makes such an approach generally useless. Unless a problem can be represented  as one of finding a circuit in a weighted graph in a natural way, TSP is likely to be practically irrelevant. In any event, this sort of question would be a better fit on [computerscience.se].

Comment: As John says, a reduction to TSP will be complex, and is likely to make the problem a lot harder.  A reduction to 3-SAT is simple, though, and 3-SAT solvers often get tested with problems like hash inversion and factoring.